# How to load bmp into GLubyte array?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

All,

I am trying to load up a bmp file into a GLubyte array (without using aux).

It is unbelievable how what I thought would have been a trivial task is sucking up hours of my time.

Can't seem to find anything on Google!

This is what I hacked together but it's not quite working:

```
// load texture

GLubyte *customTexture;

string fileName("C:\\Development\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\OpenGL_Test\\Crate.bmp");

// Use LoadImage() to get the image loaded into a DIBSection
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage( NULL, (LPCTSTR)const_cast<char*>(fileName.c_str()), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 
LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE );

customTexture = new GLubyte[3*256*256]; // size should be the size of the .bmp file

GetBitmapBits(hBitmap, 3*256*256, (LPVOID) customTexture);

GetBitmapDimensionEx(hBitmap,&szBitmap);
```

What happens is the call to LoadImage seems to be returning Undefined Value (NULL? I am not able to figure out if it's actually loading the bmp or not - a bit confused).

At the moment I am converting bmps to raw then it's all easy.

Anyone has any better and cleaner snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadImage()` can only load bitmaps that are embedded into your executable file with the resource compiler - it can't load external bitmaps from the filesystem.  Fortunately, bitmap files are really simple to read yourself.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_bitmap) for a description of the file format.

Just open up the file like you would with any other file (**important**: open it in binary mode, i.e. with the `"rb"` option using `fopen` or the `ios::binary` flag using the C++ `ifstream`), read in the bitmap dimensions, and read in the raw pixel data.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks on LoadImage - I know how to open the file with ifstream - I was kinda hoping I could find some snippet instead of going there and figure out from scratch how to read byte-by-byte (I even think I already did it smt like N years ago) since it sounds like a common task